# Ionic popover does not show if trigger ID has already been used

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with Angular 15 and Ionic 6. Everything is working fine so far except for an issue I have with popover triggers.

I've created a custom form field that opens a popover and I want to reuse this component across the application. Here is a sample of what I wrote based on the doc:

```
<div id="category-selector">
  <!-- Some HTML content -->
</div>

<ion-popover trigger="category-selector">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">Hello World!</ion-content>
  </ng-template>
</ion-popover>
```

I use this component in two separate routes. The popover will open on the first route that uses the component and will never show up on the other route. If I go back to the first route I can still open the popover. I've been using generated unique IDs as a workaround; I know that I can also use the `isOpen` property but it adds boilerplate that I'd like to avoid (this component won't be the only one embedding a popover).

I guess there are some internal Angular mechanisms behind the usage of HTML ID's that cause this "broken" behavior but I don't know what's going on exactly and how I can make it work with Ionic popovers' trigger system. Is it possible to use popovers without generating a different ID every single time, knowing that the component will never be used more than once per route anyway?

Comment: Why not just create a reusable modal service that can be used anywhere? this way is better than an inline modal.

Comment: @StackoverBlows I'm already complaining about the boilerplate added when I only want to manage a property to close/open the popover. Creating a whole new component for such a simple use case would be even worse. This isn't something that I will reuse so an inline popover is much simpler here. Besides, I can use `ng-content` in inline popovers which would be a pain in the ass to do with a separate component + service. I'm familiar with Angular Material's dialog system and know the pros and cons of a service based dialog/popover. I was glad to have a painless way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same use with Ionic Popover using with trigger-id. Even I faced so many other issues as well. So, instead of using trigger-id method, open the popover from `ViewChild` function event call.

[image]

[image]

**Note**
If you are using still facing issues with Ionic popover, below points can help you :

1. Use "Pages" instead of modules in [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate) Project.
2. Perform all actions/events using`ViewChild`
3. Use a common/shared component for your popover.

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try it out when I have a chance, thanks. FYI you should always post directly your code on Stackoverflow instead of a screenshot (it allows copy/paste as well as editing the code)

Comment: I had so many issues with the IonPopovers, my fix is I just don't use them anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Template code -->
<ion-button #btn1 (click)="presentPopover(btn1)">
  Open Popover 1
</ion-button>

<ion-button #btn2 (click)="presentPopover(btn2)">
  Open Popover 2
</ion-button>

<!-- Component code -->
async presentPopover(ev: any) {
  const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
    component: MyPopoverComponent,
    event: ev,
    translucent: true
  });

  return await popover.present();
}
```